# how to change a colour of a specific word in a line?

Tags: graphics, color, presentations

Actually I want to change colour of specific word in a line in a presentation

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
    What I have here 
    \begin{itemize}
    \item{Type A, Type B, Type B, Type D}
    \scriptsize nothing was found 
    \item{ Type C}
    \scriptsize \color{green} {a, bg4, mk1, lkt2,mm1}
    \item{ Type E}
    \scriptsize \color{green} {MB1}
    \item{ Type A }
    \scriptsize\color{green} {Redg2}
    \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}
\end {document}
```

If I do that after I adding `\color{green}` it will show everything in green after that. but I want to show for example a in green , bg4 in red and the rest in black 
then again MB1 in green 
then Redg2 in red

Comment: Use `\textcolor{green} {a}, \textcolor{red}{bg4}, mk1, lkt2,mm1` and `\textcolor{green} {MB1}` again

Comment: `\item` does not take an argument it should be `\item Type C...` your `\scriptsize` are not contained in any group other than the `itemize` so everything except the first line is in the scope of the first `\scriptsize`

Comment: @David Carlisle I dont understand your comment, can you please write it as an answer so that I will understand what you say?

Comment: OK but First fix your example so that it is a complete small example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but I meant `{}` around `\scriptsize` and no `{}` after `\item, as in Maarten's answer, so I don't thinkl another answer needed now:-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Group the text you want in a different colour and/or fontsize by putting it in between curly braces `{...}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\noindent What I have here 
\begin{itemize}
    \item Type A, Type B, Type B, Type D {\scriptsize nothing was found}
    \item Type C {\scriptsize \color{green} a}, {\scriptsize \color{red} bg4}, {\scriptsize mk1, lkt2,mm1}
    \item Type E {\scriptsize \color{green} MB1}
    \item Type A Down {\scriptsize \color{red} Redg2}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this makes all the line after TypeC in green, which I don't want to show everything in green

Comment: @Nemo Then group them accordingly as you can see in my edited asnwer.

Comment: that is very nice, is it also possible to add a line of text after the Type A with 2 cm distance from it ? because when I use \noindent\scriptsize TEXT TEXT TEXT  , it brings it very close to that line

Comment: @Nemo Are you talking about horizontal or vertical 2cm distance. Is this the first Type A, or the second Type A Down? You will need to be more specific when asking questions!

Comment: horizontal 2 cm under the TypeA Down Redg2. (can i also make some space in vertical for that line for example 1 cm from the edge)

Comment: `\hspace{2cm}{\scriptsize TEXT TEXT TEXT}`

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
What I have here 
\begin{itemize}
\item{Type A, Type B, Type B, Type D}
\scriptsize nothing was found 
\item{Type C}
\scriptsize {\color{green}{a}}, {\color{red}{bg4}}, mk1, lkt2, mm1
\item{Type E}
\scriptsize {\color{green}{MB1}}
\item{Type A Down }
\scriptsize {\color{red}{Redg2}}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

And for the next time, please provide a complete minimal example. You have already asked enough questions that you should know that.